# Python Re: Multiple Capturing Groups

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group, capturing-group

I have a problem building a working and correct pattern to re.finditer with multiple capturing groups in a pattern. I have the following string I want to search for data.

```
search_string="""
option.Map['2015'] = new CG.New.Option('text1', '2015', 100, 200);
option.Map['2016'] = new CG.New.Option('text2', '2016', 150, 210);
option.Map['2017'] = new CG.New.Option('text3', '2017', 160, 260);
"""
```

I would like to use Python regex to extract the text, the year, and the numbers. My pattern looks like the following:

```
pattern=r"option.Map\[\'(.*)\'] = new CG\.New\.Option\(\'(.*)\',\'(.*)\',(.*),(.*)\);"
```

My code looks like the following:

```
for finding in re.finditer(pattern,search_string):
    print(finding.group(1))
    print(finding.group(2))
    print(finding.group(3))
    print(finding.group(4))
    print(finding.group(5))
```

I know that my pattern is off, but I don't know why.

The output I would expect/want to achieve looks like the following:

```
2015
text1
2015
100
200
2016
text2
2016
150
210
2017
text3
2017
160
260
```

Comment: Does `unbalanced parenthesis at position 72` give a hint?

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the hint. Updated the problem. Prints zero findings still though.

Comment: You're not catering for spaces... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take into account the spaces after the numbers, eg:

```
import re

search_string = """
option.Map['2015'] = new CG.New.Option('text1', '2015', 100, 200);
option.Map['2016'] = new CG.New.Option('text2', '2016', 150, 210);
option.Map['2017'] = new CG.New.Option('text3', '2017', 160, 260);
"""

pattern = r"option.Map\['(.*?)'\] = new CG.New.Option\('(.*?)', '(.*?)', (\d+), (\d+)\);"
```

Then:

```
for match in re.finditer(pattern, search_string):
    print(*match.groups(), sep='\n')
```

Gives you:

```
2015
text1
2015
100
200
2016
text2
2016
150
210
2017
text3
2017
160
260
```